# Как остановить цикл отдельной командой в python(telebot)?

Tags: python, telebot

есть код, не знаю как его остановить отдельной командой. Если использовать bot.stop_polling(), то бот выключается в целом, приходится его перезапускать, а мне нужно сохранять его дальнейшую работу без перезапусков. Я подумал, что можно сделать перезапуск бота, но не нашёл в интернете, как это можно реализовать.
Цикл который нужно остановить:

```
#Спам сообщения в случайное время
@bot.message_handler(commands=['x'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'x')
    i = 1 
    while 1 == 1:
        time.sleep(random.randrange(1,3600,1))
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'x')
        i += 1
```

Comment: Посмотрите, может быть поможет: https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/cikly-for-i-while-operatory-break-i-continue-volshebnoe-slovo-else.html

Answer (score 0):

Возможно Вам сможет помочь команда break или continue. [Их краткое описание](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/cikly-for-i-while-operatory-break-i-continue-volshebnoe-slovo-else.html)